# firebase_auth ^3.11.2 depends on firebase_auth_web ^4.6.1 which depends on intl ^0.17.0, firebase_auth ^3.11.2 requires intl ^0.17.0

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I am getting this error while running with firebase_auth ^3.11.2  intl ^0.18.1

```
Because firebase_auth ^3.11.2 depends on firebase_auth_web ^4.6.1 which depends on intl ^0.17.0, firebase_auth ^3.11.2 requires intl ^0.17.0.
So, because e-com depends on both firebase_auth ^3.11.2 and intl ^0.18.1, version solving failed.
```

and I'm getting this error while changing to intl ^0.17.0.

```
Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.1 and e-com depends on intl 0.17.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is forbidden.
So, because e-com depends on flutter_localizations from sdk, version solving failed.
```